Correction Factor of Log Mean Temperature Difference
Background
In thermal equilibrium without phase change, the heat transfer $Q$ between two fluids with parallel flow or counter flow configuration is expressed as
\begin{align}
    Q \; = \; U A \; LMTD
\end{align}
where $U$ is the heat transfer coefficients, $A$ is the contact area for heat exchange, and $LMTD$ is the log mean temperature difference given by
\begin{align}
    LMTD \; = \; \frac{\Delta T_{A} \; - \Delta T_{B}}{\ln\big(\frac{\Delta T_{A}}{\Delta T_{B}}\big)}
\end{align}
$\Delta T_{A}$ and $\Delta T_{B}$ is the temperature difference between two fluid at terminal $A$ and $B$ respectively
To extend to other flow configurations, it is said that a correction factor is multiplied to $LMTD$, such that this equation hold
\begin{align}
    Q \; = \; UA \; \big(F \times LMTD \big)
\end{align}
where $F$ is temperature dependent.
Question
It is interesting to see that for any flow configuration, $Q \; = \; UA \; \big(F \times LMTD \big)$ still holds. It looks like $F$ alone capture the flow configuration, and the $LMTD$ is factorised out from the integral. Is there any mathematical derivation?

For any particular flow configuration, you have to derive F separately, or have its value pre-tabulated in a table.

FWIW, ISO-80000-2 (paywalled, unfortunately), recommends using single letters for variables. Things like $LMTD$ look to be the product for 4 variables, rather than some function of temperature. It probably would be better to write it as a function like $f(T_a,T_b)=(T_a-T_b)/\log(T_a/T_b)$ or similar.
